# jQuery combine the "altField" with +1 year added to the selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This code below is not working as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#txtDateIssued').datepicker({

        altField: "#txtDateExpires",
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

        onSelect: function(dateStr) {

            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
            d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);

            $('#txtDateExpires').datepicker('setDate', d);

        }

    });

});
```

We need to combine the `altField` with +1 year added to the selected date and be displayed in the `altField`, not another input with datepicker. The reason is we don't want the added year to be accessible/editable by the user and not have a datepicker for this date. Just an information display of +1 year.

Jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/2hn4hchk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the replies. The code below is working perfect. Hope it helps others with the same issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#txtDateIssued').datepicker({
 altField: "#txtDateExpires",
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

 onSelect: function(dateStr) {

         var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);

         d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);

         dateFormatted = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
         + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
         + d.getFullYear();

         $('#txtDateExpires').val(dateFormatted);

         }

     });

 });
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2hn4hchk/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onSelect` to `setDate` instead of `setFullYear` and add 365 days to current selected `date` as below. Also, I suppose you don't need to initialize `datepicker` on 2nd `input` unless you are using it.

```
onSelect: function(dateStr) {
  var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 365); //setDate and getDate+365
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
  $('#txtDateExpires').val(someFormattedDate);
}
```

## [`Working DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2hn4hchk/1/)

> **Note - You can remove the `altField` property too as part of initialization option since you don't need it now. Thanks to [`Rory McCrossan`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) for the suggestion**

---

**Updating answer to take care of leap year**

```
onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
        var isLeap = new Date(d.getFullYear()+1, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1 && d.getMonth()+1!=2; //check for leap year and month.
        var days=isLeap?(365+1):365;
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + days);
        var dd = d.getDate();
        var mm = ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var y = d.getFullYear();
        var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
        $('#txtDateExpires').val(someFormattedDate);
}
```

## [`Updated Working DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2hn4hchk/7/)

Comment: Good answer, as you included date formatting. Note that you shouldn't add 365 days though, because of leap years. The OPs original logic was better in that regard. You can also remove the `altField` property. +1 regardless

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao: Thank you for the answer, but it shows the month as single digit format. We need the same format to match as in 31/12/2016. The leading 0 is missing if month is less than 10. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @sitedevcode `var mm = ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao: Great work! Just yet the same issue with leading 0 in single digit day. I tried to fix it with `var dd = ('00' + (d.getDate).slice(-2));` but it breaks the logic. Any fix as well?

Comment: @sitedevcode.. Check the **Updated Working Demo**!! and do accept the answer if it was helpful..

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao: +1 Vote. I tried to upvote for leading me to the right direction but the system refused as I am low in reputation! I upated the answer with a mixed of my original code with your formatting idea and setting the val to the formatted. You did help and I appreciate it very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: You can tick mark the `right` icon below the `+1 vote`.. :)